# Debugging: Android studio causes app to crash, when stepping over to exit a method

Tags: debugging, android-studio

I am running Android Studio 2.1.1 and debugging my app on two devices (one emulator on my x86_64 windows 10, the other is my HTC One M8). During debugging, if I step over codes, and when it exists the current method or scope, the program just crashes, without any indication in logcat (I know this because I purposely added a log.d to be the last line, and the last message I got is the content from this log.d before crashing).

However, if I use continue rather than step over, the app just exits the current function fine, without crashing the app.

I have no idea what is going on here, it drastically slows down my development and debugging. Any ideas and suggestions will be appreciated. Please let me know if you need more info, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know who down-voted my question... An obsoleted question bothers you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue.  However, poking around online, I found this:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200880

- It's a known issue that affects **Android 6** (Marshmallow) devices and emulators only.
- There is no workaround, except to use an Android 4/5/7 device for debugging, or to use 'Continue' instead of 'Step Over'.

If anyone finds a fix/workaround, it would be helpful!

Comment: Month later, still broken for me, have you see any update on this?

Comment: I have not unfortunately.  I just put a breakpoint where I expect it to go later in the code and let it run until it hits it.  I wish this was fixed soon :(

Comment: Interestingly, I only noticed this issue after updating to 2.2.2, whereas before it seemed to work fine - maybe it only occurs in some cases.

Comment: Using Studio 3.0 with Android 6 (Nexus) while steeping over still exits the app without any indication !

Comment: i have the same problem on a Nexus 5 Android 6... still in 2020

Comment: Still same in March 2021