# Android studio - App Crashes on Step Over

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing crash in Android studio while in debugging mode when I am doing step over (short key F8). If I put breakpoints then it is jumping to next breakpoints (with short key F9). I am getting below error

```
A/zygote: jdwp_handler.cc:1221] Check failed: modifier_count < 256 (modifier_count=268, 256=256) 
    runtime.cc:542] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:542] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3474 (JDWP), pid 3461 (bundle identifier)
```

I have checked many documents and stack answers but not found exact solutions.
some of similar issue I checked. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495131/debugging-android-studio-causes-app-to-crash-when-stepping-over-to-exit-a-meth) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67243671/android-studio-ide-debugging-step-into-over-crashing-app)

I am running with `Android studio 4.2.1` - Ubuntu, Project is build with latest `sdk version 30`. Testing with `Android Oreo devices`

Comment: exactly same problem, f9 works fine but the app crashes when i press f8

Answer (score 0):

Set `Debug type: Dual(Java + Native)` from Android `studio > Run > Edit Configurations...` As I checked for project based on Java code, debugging was working properly but for Kotlin code was not working debugging. It was giving crash for Step Over. After changing this it is working for Kotlin code. Hope this will help someone if facing same problem as I faced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem on all hardware devices I have. There are Android 8.1.0, Android 6.0.
I recently saw it on emulators, but it was easy to handle - just reinstall the AVD and it is gone. Now I need to test on hardware devices and nothing works.

Here is the issue at Google, and it looks like they are not going to fix it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37081686